# How to control max-width using divs within another div?

Tags: html, css

Right now I am creating a website and I have text boxes style close to each other each using a unique div. When I resize the browser the divs over lap each other so I was thinking of using max-width to keep everything together. I have successfully used this code

```
html {
min-width: 1000px;
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100%;
}
```

to keep the max-width at 1000px but my text boxes are ignoring this and just doing their own thing. I tried to create a div to control all my divs but it is not working. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

HTML: http://pastebin.com/tSXwCmPf
CSS: http://pastebin.com/vEzqxSRW

Comment: Please put your html code

Comment: can you provide a pastebin compiled codes ?

Comment: Done, i have my codes on pastebin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<div class="wrapper">` was closed incorrectly the closing bracket needs to be at the bottom of your code for the elements to adapt the `min-width`.

`<div class="wrapper">
     <img src="images/LOGO.png"/>
     <ul class="menu">
         <li><a href="../menu.html">Menu</a></li>
         <li><a href="../map.html">Map</a></li>
         <li><a href="../info.html">Store Info</a></li>
         <li id="no-link">Order Now</li>
     </ul>
     /* other html code needs to be here */
 </div> /*This </div> needs to be after your blocks */`

`div.wrapper {
     width: 120%;
     min-width: 1000px;
     height: auto;
     position: relative;
     left: -10%;
     margin-top: 17%
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You can mark as !important with width than it wont ignore it. Try following :

max-width: 1000px !important;